# Default behavior with publication lists when a new subscriber is added to All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I can't seem to find any documentation on this but when a new subscriber is added to All Subscribers are they by default added to all publication lists?

Answer (score 2):

They are added to the publication list when they are sent to for the first time.

Comment: So if a subscriber is sent an email that doesn't fall into any publication list (basically like a catch all) are they not added to any pub list (only all subs)?

Comment: Nope, they will only be added to a publication list if they are associated to the send. Or if you add it in via API/Ampscript